# SSH connection with public key not working with specific name

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

When trying to connect to a server with:

```
ssh -i MYKEY_SSH user@IP
```

It prompts for the password. However, if I rename that key for any other name the connection is properly established.

That is, if I do:

```
cp MYKEY_SSH whatever_ssh
```

then

```
ssh -i whatever_ssh user@IP
```

Is able to connect directly.

I can't figure out where is the problem.

No particular ssh config in my local system and no change in the permissions when renaming.

In a unsuccesful SSH key connection the debug says:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: vm@localhost.localdomain
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: key_ssh
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

And in a succesful one I see that after that it says:

```
debug1: Trying private key: key_ssh
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to IP ([IP]:22).
```

Comment: Try running ssh with the "-vv" flag to print debugging info. Do it both for the key that works and the key that doesn't. Then [edit] your question to include the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1424281/sshd-wont-accept-key-but-only-if-named-id-rsa) I have an id_rsa.pub file which does not match the main key file, so that was the cause of the problem.